# knotes note location

Tags: notes

[image: Knotes]

I use **Knotes** to writes notes and then I like to put all those notes on my Desktop

But the problem is:

Everytime I reboot my Ubuntu The location of notes stored on desktops changes and the note
is shifted to places like **behind the Dock** or **half part on the edge of desktop** etc..

Hence everytime I log on to ubuntu I have to reset the position of the notes.

Why is this happening and How should I stop this strange behaviour of notes?

I have tried reinstalling **Knotes** but it doesn't help!

Thanks you in advanced!

Comment: Was the answer helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>**Warning:** Alternative software, not a solution ahead; you are warned!</sub>

I would rather recommend to use [Xpad](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/xpad/), a much better software to store notes. knotes is probably *optimized* for KDE environment and *may* not work very well on Unity interfaces.

To start xpad when you reboot your system, do this:

- Type "Startup applications" on the dash and open the application
- In the window that pops-up, click on "Add"
- In th dialog box that pops-up, enter "xpad" as the name and `xpad` as the command and "notes" as comment and then click on "Add".

Comment: I forgot to accept it! :p

Answer (score -1):

Do you have Compiz running, and your KNotes are in Rich-Text mode?
KNotes Rich-Text mode causes the KNotes to change size, in a way that messes up Compiz's placement of KNotes. (or at least that's what it looks like to me)

If you leave the KNotes in Rich-Text edit mode, and turn off Compiz, The Knotes Shrink vertically every reshowing of KNotes, but at least they keep their position for the most part.

Turning off Rich-Text mode in KNotes fixes these problems, but you're left with plain text after each login. (no bold, italic, underline, multiple fonts, etc...)